# "rvm use --install" broken in Jenkins, "uname: command not found"

Tags: ruby, jenkins, rvm, ubuntu-14.04, rbenv

This is a snippet from a Jenkins job run that needs rvm 1.9.3..  I have no idea why the PATH is not being looked at.  From this build the PATH environment variable looks correctly set as `PATH="/usr/java/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"` (as set in /etc/environment), `HOME="/scratch"` and `SHELL="/bin/sh"`, so I'm mystified by this.

```
$ bash -c " source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm && rvm use --install --create ruby-1.9.3 && export > rvm.env"
/scratch/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 12: uname: command not found
/scratch/.rvm/scripts/rvm: line 15: ps: command not found
bash: rvm: command not found
```

I have also attempted the rbenv route but am met with similar errors indicating the absence of `$PATH`

Also, the Jenkins user belongs to the `rvm` group.

I send many internets in thanks for any assistance offered!

Answer (score 0):

rvm needs login shell.

I use it like this in my builds:

```
echo "rvm install 2.2.3" | /bin/bash -l
```

Works just fine this way.